# Kеrаs сказала мне, что модель имеет 1 выход, но я подумала, что если у нее больше

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras

У меня есть набор данных `df` для многоклассовой проблемы классификации. У меня огромный классовый дисбаланс. А именно, `grade_F` и `grade_G`.

```
>>> percentage = 1. / df['grade'].value_counts(normalize=True)
>>> print(percentage )

B    0.295436
C    0.295362
A    0.204064
D    0.136386
E    0.048788
F    0.014684
G    0.005279
```

В то же время у меня есть очень нестандартные прогнозы для менее представленных классов, как можно видеть [здесь](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/60194/improving-classifcation-when-some-are-less-represented).

У меня есть нейронная сеть с выходным измерением 7, то есть массив, который я хочу спрогнозировать:

```
>>> print(y_train.head())
        grade_A  grade_B  grade_C  grade_D  grade_E  grade_F  grade_G
689526        0        1        0        0        0        0        0
523913        1        0        0        0        0        0        0
266122        0        0        1        0        0        0        0
362552        0        0        0        1        0        0        0
484987        1        0        0        0        0        0        0
...
```

Поэтому я попробовал следующую нейронную сеть:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.constraints import maxnorm

def create_model(input_dim, output_dim):
    print(output_dim)
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    # input layer
    model.add(Dense(100, input_dim=input_dim, activation='relu', kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    # hidden layer
    model.add(Dense(60, activation='relu', kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    # output layer
    model.add(Dense(output_dim, activation='softmax'))

    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', loss_weights=lossWeights, optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.models import load_model

model = create_model(x_train.shape[1], y_train.shape[1])

epochs =  35
batch_sz = 64

print("Beginning model training with batch size {} and {} epochs".format(batch_sz, epochs))

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("lc_model.h5", monitor='val_acc', verbose=0, save_best_only=True, mode='auto', period=1)
# train the model
history = model.fit(x_train.as_matrix(),
                y_train.as_matrix(),
                validation_split=0.2,
                epochs=epochs,  
                batch_size=batch_sz, # Can I tweak the batch here to get evenly distributed data ?
                verbose=2,
                callbacks=[checkpoint])

# revert to the best model encountered during training
model = load_model("lc_model.h5")
```

Поэтому я подал вектор весов обратно пропорционально частоте класса:

```
lossWeights = df['grade'].value_counts(normalize=True)
lossWeights = lossWeights.sort_index().tolist()
```

Тем не менее, он сказал мне, что объем производства был размером 1:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-bf262c22c9dc> in <module>
      2 from keras.models import load_model
      3 
----> 4 model = create_model(x_train.shape[1], y_train.shape[1])
      5 
      6 epochs =  35

<ipython-input-65-9290b177bace> in create_model(input_dim, output_dim)
     19 
     20     # Compile model
---> 21     model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', loss_weights=lossWeights, optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
     22     return model

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in compile(self, optimizer, loss, metrics, loss_weights, sample_weight_mode, weighted_metrics, target_tensors, **kwargs)
    178                                  'The model has ' + str(len(self.outputs)) +
    179                                  ' outputs, but you passed loss_weights=' +
--> 180                                  str(loss_weights))
    181             loss_weights_list = loss_weights
    182         else:

ValueError: When passing a list as loss_weights, it should have one entry per model output. The model has 1 outputs, but you passed loss_weights=[4.9004224502112255, 3.3848266392035704, 3.385677583130476, 7.33212052000478, 20.49667767920116, 68.10064134188455, 189.42024013722127]
```

## Обновить

Вот он `model.summary`:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_25 (Dense)             (None, 100)               10600     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_17 (Dropout)         (None, 100)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_26 (Dense)             (None, 60)                6060      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_18 (Dropout)         (None, 60)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_27 (Dense)             (None, 7)                 427       
=================================================================
Total params: 17,087
Trainable params: 17,087
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Я ошибался. мне пришлось поместить веса, которые будут присваиваться классам в `class_weight` в `model.fit()`:

Чтобы получить их  :

```
from sklearn.utils import class_weight

class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced',
                                                 np.unique(y_train),
                                                 y_train)
```

Тем не менее, я получаю :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-9d3f1efebd10> in <module>
      3 class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced',
      4                                                  np.unique(y_train),
----> 5                                                  y_train)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\sklearn\utils\class_weight.py in compute_class_weight(class_weight, classes, y)
     39 
     40     if set(y) - set(classes):
---> 41         raise ValueError("classes should include all valid labels that can "
     42                          "be in y")
     43     if class_weight is None or len(class_weight) == 0:

ValueError: classes should include all valid labels that can be in y
```

Поэтому я попытался сделать это вручную и передал параметр `class_weight` в `model.fit()`, который представляет собой список инвертированной частоты классов в наборе данных:

```
>>> lossWeights = df['grade'].value_counts(normalize=True)
>>> lossWeights = lossWeights.sort_index().tolist()
>>> print(lossWeights)
[0.204064039408867, 0.2954361054766734, 0.29536185163720663, 0.13638619240799768, 0.04878839466821211, 0.014684149521877717, 0.0052792668791654595]
weights = {0: 1 / 0.204064,
       1: 1 / 0.295436, 
       2: 1 / 0.295362,
       3: 1 / 0.136386, 
       4: 1 / 0.048788,
       5: 1 / 0.014684,
       6: 1 / 0.005279}

history = model.fit(x_train.as_matrix(),
                y_train.as_matrix(),
                validation_split=0.2,
                epochs=epochs,  
                batch_size=batch_sz, # Can I tweak the batch here to get evenly distributed data ?
                verbose=2,
                class_weight = weights,
                callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

Он уменьшился в тесте на точность задания: 86,57% (ранее 88,54%), но лучше сбалансировал результаты в матрице путаницы:

[image]

Так что это еще не то, чего я жду. Сейчас я думаю об искусственном добавлении данных из классов, которые недостаточно представлены. Клонирование или удаление данных из других классов. В противном случае, меня интересуют характеристики. Я думал о том, чтобы сделать PCA, но не знаю, как это сделать в Пайтоне.

Comment: можете привести в вопросе вывод `model.summary()` ?

Comment: @MaxU Да, конечно, конечно! Вот даже [jupyter notebook](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/antoinecomp/multiclass_prediction/blob/master/Loans.ipynb).

Comment: Для выравнивания несбалансированных данных существует модуль [imbalanced-learn](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#module-imblearn.over_sampling)